# Validate commit message in git

Tags: git, pre-commit

How to validate the commit message in precommit?

The commit message should be valid for the following condition.

the prefix of the commit message should be like `feature({A-Z}:{0-9}): 'commit message'`

I am a beginner for git

Comment: What do you mean by "validate the commit message"?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin sorry for this i have mentioned

Comment: @AkbarBasha I am looking for same thing. Please help me if you got the answer

Comment: @Ajit i did using gulp task.

find the code below,

gulp.task('commit-message', function (done) {
    // Get commit message from git commit edit message file   
  let msg = fs.readFileSync('.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG', 'utf8');
    msg = msg.split('\n').join(' ');
    if (!RegExp(regexp.COMMIT_TYPES).test(msg)) {
      const error = '\n The template: \n <jira-id>{spac}: <summary> \n\n Example: \n PWA-01 : Fixed bug \n\n';
      // console.log(error);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
    else {
        // Allow git commit
        process.exitCode = 0;
    }
    done();
});

Answer (score 1):

In your local copy, your `.git/hooks` folder contains a set of `.sample` files. For your specific case, you would use the `commit-msg.sample` file.

```
$            cd .git/hooks
.git/hooks$  cp commit-msg.sample commit-msg
.git/hooks$  cat commit-msg
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to check the commit log message.
# Called by "git commit" with one argument, the name of the file
# that has the commit message.  The hook should exit with non-zero
# status after issuing an appropriate message if it wants to stop the
# commit.  The hook is allowed to edit the commit message file.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "commit-msg".

# Uncomment the below to add a Signed-off-by line to the message.
# Doing this in a hook is a bad idea in general, but the prepare-commit-msg
# hook is more suited to it.
#
# SOB=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p')
# grep -qs "^$SOB" "$1" || echo "$SOB" >> "$1"

# This example catches duplicate Signed-off-by lines.

test "" = "$(grep '^Signed-off-by: ' "$1" |
     sort | uniq -c | sed -e '/^[   ]*1[    ]/d')" || {
    echo >&2 Duplicate Signed-off-by lines.
    exit 1
}
```

You can modify this script as you see fit. When you `exit 1`, the commit process will halt instead of completing successfully.